# Render several mermaid diagrams added by javascript

Tags: javascript, mermaid

I have a dynamic webpage that can contain several mermaid diagrams. These diagrams are embedded into a webpage as a source code (e.g. in `<pre>` tags) and then should be processed by mermaid to be replaced with the actual diagrams. Currently, I have two problems:

1. The approach that I found (adapting answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65212332/how-to-render-a-mermaid-flowchart-dynamically)) does not work with the latest version of mermaid.
2. It does not work with several diagrams, only the last one is processed.

Here is what I have now. I mock the script that adds diagrams with `add_diagram`. Then, if I run `make_diagrams()`, only the second one is rendered. Also, it doesn't work correctly if I switch to the latest version of mermaid.

```js
function add_diagram() {
  diagram_code = `
  <pre class="mermaid">
    graph TD
    A[First diagram] --> B[Something]
  </pre>
  <pre class="mermaid">
    graph TD
    A[Second diagram] --> B[Something]
  </pre>
  `;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += diagram_code;
}
function make_diagrams() {
  $("pre.mermaid").each(function() {
    mermaid.render(
      "body", 
      this.textContent, 
      (function (code) {this.outerHTML = code}).bind(this))
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="output"/>
<button onclick="add_diagram()">add diagram</button>
<button onclick="make_diagrams()">make diagrams</button>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to make it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that the second diagram is rendered with the same ID as the first one - this is overwriting the content. You need to render all diagrams with a unique ID.

Also, I'd suggest that do not use `onclick`, especially if you are already using `jQuery`.

```js
function addDiagram() {
  return `
  <pre class="mermaid">
    graph TD
    A[First diagram] --> B[Something]
  </pre>
  <pre class="mermaid">
    graph TD
    A[Second diagram] --> B[Something]
  </pre>
  `;
}

$(".add-diagram").on("click", function() {
  $("#output").html(addDiagram())
})

const appendDiagramTo = (el) => (code) => el.outerHTML = code

function renderDiagram(id, el) {
  mermaid.render(
    id,
    el.textContent,
    appendDiagramTo(el)
  )
}

$(".make-diagrams").on("click", function() {
  $("pre.mermaid").each(function(i, e) {
    // creating the container ID -> this is NOT unique, so if you have
    // multiple places on your page rendering multiple diagrams, you
    // should update this to be really unique
    const containerId = `mermaid-${i}`

    // rendering the diagram with the unique ID
    renderDiagram(containerId, e)
  })

})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<button class="add-diagram">add diagram</button>
<button class="make-diagrams">make diagrams</button>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```